# How to change TFS 2012 default workspace map local to server

Tags: tfs

could you help me about this problem. We have to re-config all clients after get latest version of workspace local to server.

I want to set the default setting of TFS 2012 default workspace mapping setting to server.

Thanks for your helps..

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to launch `Team Explorer` and go to the `Settings page`. Under `Team Project Collection`, select `Source Control`. On the “`Workspace Settings`” tab, you can change the default `workspace type` from local to server.

Comment: *Workspace Settings* is missing in my case.

Answer (score 7):

Open `Source Control Explorer`, then click `Workspaces...` under workspace dropdown. After selecting workspace click `Edit`, then `Advanced`. There you can switch between Local and Server workspace location.