# How to configure Team Foundation Server 2015 to force all workspaces to be local only?

Tags: tfs

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2015 `14.102.25423.0` and until now all of the team's developers have configured their workspaces to be **server**.

Now because of a policy change, we want to make all workspaces local.

Of course, one option is to go to each developer and make that change inside Visual Studio.

But I wonder if there is a way to force it from the server?

Answer (score 0):

We create and work with workspaces using visual studio to connect Azure DevOps Server as this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=tfs-2015) stated.

Thus I am afraid that the only option is to go to each developer and make that change inside Visual Studio if you want to change workspace from server to local. You need to go to `File -> Source Control -> Workspaces` (`File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces` for VS2017), then select your workspace (it should match your computer name) and click `Edit`, then `Advanced`. There you can switch between Local and Server workspace location. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349957/how-to-change-tfs-2012-default-workspace-map-local-to-server) for more details.

In addition, if you are an [administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?viewFallbackFrom=vsts&view=tfs-2015), you can specify which type of workspace Visual Studio creates for your team members by default: Local or Server.

1. On the menu bar, choose **Team**, **Project Collection Settings**, **Source Control**.

   The **Source Control Settings** dialog box appears.
2. On the **Workspace Settings** tab, choose either the **Local** or **Server** option button.

See: [Decide between using a local or a server workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=tfs-2015) for more details.